# Trying to parse a string delimited by | and I want to ignore " | | | | " but it does not work

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, whitespace

So I am parsing a string and I am tokenizing it using | as a delimiter. However, I want to make sure that I do not parse spaces ( in any amount ) and simply ignore them. However for some reason, nothing is working completely. Some spaces escape the check and get printed. here is my code:

```
white = value;
white.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '');
if(white != null && white != '' && white != ' '){
   console.log("IT IS NOT EMPTY");
}else{
   console.log("IT IS EMPTY");
}
```

I cannot understand it.

These work:

```
" | "
" | | | "
```

BUT

```
" |   | | | "
```

does NOT work...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.replace` does not transform the string, it returns the new string.

```
white = white.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
```

Comment: That will remove spaces **only** from the beginning of the string and the end of the string, not between `|` characters.

Comment: my goal is to determine if |  |  |   |      |  contains only whitespaces. or either of the parts is composed only of white spaces hence "dasdsa|     |dasds |     |   " will evaluate to empty 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to break the string into parts based on the `|`, ignoring spaces before or after it, then:

```
var parts = value.split(/\s*\|\s*/);
```

That expression says: Split on optional whitespace followed by a literal `|` (you have to escape them in regular expressions) followed by optional whitespace.

If your goal is to remove spaces that are adjacent to a `|` from the string, then:

```
white = value.replace(/(?:\s+\|)|(?:\|\s+)/g, "|");
```

That regular expression says: If you find a sequence of spaces followed by a literal `|`, **or** a sequence of space following a literal `|`, replace them (including the `|`) with a single `|`. The unescaped `|` within the expression is an "alternation" meaning "either of the things on either side of me."